# Do not allow all domain users to have access to a shared folder

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, domain

This should be easy, but I just don't see it. And, first, I'm a programmer wearing the hat of an IT for lack of resource where I work (small company).

I need to create a folder, inside our network share, that only a certain group of people should have access to. Now, I open the Security tab and I just want to "not allow full control on all domain users", but the options are greyed.

[image]

In Linux, this would only require me to change the group of the folder to one that only certain people are assigned to and the job would be done. How do I do this in Windows Server 2008 RC2?

A dumb idea would be to individually add all the domain users and restrict them... then any new users would have access to the resource. So, no thank you.

This may seem easy, but I'm neither an IT, nor a Windows user.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those permissions are being inherited from the parent folder. You'll need to remove/disable inheritance on this folder in order to change those permissions.

Comment: I thought I had checked, but I found the source of the net drive, and deselected the domain user. Thanks!